# parse XLS file with protected protected workbook

Tags: php, excel, parsing

I need to read data from XLS files that are marked as protected workbooks (of which I have the password). I cannot find any PHP libraries that allows for this functionality, so am looking into writing the code to do so myself. I can't seem to find any information on how the protection is applied, going by [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2003-resource-kit/important-aspects-of-password-and-encryption-protection-HA001140311.aspx), it is not clear whether any encryption is applied in the case of a protected workbook (selecting protect workbook in the Excel menu). If any encryption is applied, how do you determine which method is applied? The following options are listed:

Weak Encryption (XOR)
Office 97/2000 Compatible
RC4, Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0
RC4, Microsoft Base DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider
RC4, Microsoft DH SChannel Cryptographic Provider
RC4, Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
RC4, Microsoft Enhanced DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider
RC4, Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)
RC4, Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
RC4, Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider

When parsing the file with PHP, it does seem like some encryption is applied, as I get jibberish tokens after the FILEPASS (0x2f) token is read. (In this case I just ignored the FILEPASS token)

Are there any libraries that can read data of a protected workbook? (preferably PHP). Any sources which explain how the encryption is done?

Comment: Have you looked at how PHPExcel handles protected workbooks?

Comment: From what I have read PHPExcel does not support protected workbooks. Maybe support had been added at some stage, I'll look again. I did use PHPExcel before and got the same symptoms that I am getting now (empty list of sheets when parsing). However, I did not realize at that stage that the protection on the worksheet gave issues so it is quite possible that I needed to apply some setting or something. Could you please supply a link where I can get the most information on how PHPExcel handles protected worksheets? (Seeing as I have missed it...) Greatly appreciated

Comment: Support for Protected (RC4 encrypted) .xls files was added in PHPExcel version 1.8.0.... it's Open Source, so you can find all the code at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel